# AAD - External users not automatically added to the Users list

Tags: azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc, multiple-users

I'm creating a MVC core app that uses Azure Active Directory (AAD) as user storage.
I can create users manually in the AAD Users dashboard screen and invite external users without problems. They can also login into the app without issues.
Uninvited external users can also login to the app when agreeing with the consent screen which is what i want.
My question however is how can i keep track of those users in AAD? They are not listed in the Users dashboard as external users nor are they logged in the 'Sign-ins' log screen.
Is there some option that i need to enable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to use external users in your application, I would suggest that you use the Azure AD B2C solution:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/technical-overview

This will create a new B2C tenant from which you can track users that have integrated and logged in your application.

Check the consumer accounts section to see if this matched your needs:

> Consumer accounts
>
> With a consumer account, users can sign in to the applications that you've secured with Azure AD B2C. Users with consumer accounts can't, however, access Azure resources, for example the Azure portal.

Comment: That's exactly what i need. I was too focused on AAD and external users that i overlooked the AAD B2C solution. For those who want some useful info about the different AAD flavors i've found this link very interesting: https://www.predicagroup.com/blog/azure-ad-b2b-b2c-puzzled-out/